# Poisson Distribution - The Equidispersion Property

Tags: probability

I wondered if someone would take the time to provide a simple numerical example of the equidispersion property. When it is likely to arise. And the type of data that would satisfy this property.

I should state that I understand that equidispersion indicates that the variance is equal to the mean. However, admittedly, I don't quite understand the conditions necessary for this to happen, or a real world example of this.

Would be very helpful to hear some input on the matter from mathematicians and statisticians alike.

Best,

Andrew

Comment: Crosspost of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438612/the-poisson-regression-the-equidispersion-property 5 days ago

Answer (score 0):

In the header of your question you said that Poisson distribution has equidispersion property. Yes, this is true for all possible parameters.

However, there are other distributions that also have it. Examples include:

[Normal distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) $N(a, a)$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$

[Exponential distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with parameter $1$

[Uniform distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) on $[a, a - 3 + \sqrt{12a + 9}]$

and many others...